# Calling paperclip image as deeply nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, paperclip

I have been struggling with this problem for almost a month now and can't seem to figure it out.  I am rather new to RoR and am sure there is something basic I am overlooking...  Help is really appreciated!

I have three resources nested into one another: (1) Books, (2) Chapters, (3) Pages.  The Page model has an image attribute via the paperclip gem.

The models for each are below:

```
  class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :synopsis, :title   
  has_many :chapters

  class Chapters < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :synopsis, :title    
  belongs_to :book
  has_many :pages

  class Pages < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :page_image, :page_number
  has_attached_file :page_image, styles: { medium: "1024x768>",  thumb: "300x300>" }
  belongs_to :chapter
```

As you can see, each page has an image.  In the Book **show** page, I want to have a section that displays all the Chapters that belong to that Book, and the link of each Chapter would be the image of the first page belonging to that Chapter.

Book controller:

```
class BookController < ApplicationController
...
def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    @chapters = @book.chapters.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @book }
    end
  end
...
```

Book's show view:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <% @chapters.each do |chapter| %>
  <li class="span3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <%= image_tag chapter.pages.first.page_image %>
    </div>
  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Here is the error I get:

```
undefined method `page_image' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #5):

2:   <% @chapters.each do |chapter| %>
3:   <li class="span3">
4:     <div class="thumbnail">
5:      <%= image_tag chapter.pages.first.page_image %>
6:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do all of your chapters have pages? It looks like one of them does not, and `first` is returning `nil`.

```
chapter.pages.first.page_image
```

Means, for the given chapter (from `@chapters`), get an array of pages. Take the first page (or `nil` if there are no pages). Call `page_image` on it.

What you probably want is something like

```
image_tag chapter.pages.first.try(:page_image).try(:url, :thumb)
```

The [try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) method will test if the object it is being called on is `nil`, and if it is, will return `nil` instead of causing an exception.

Comment: wow thanks.  Although I had images attached already, your solution worked.  Really appreciate it.